# Why is PHP PDO DSN a different format for MySQL versus PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

When I connect to a MySQL database using PDO, the way I need to connect is:

```
$pdoConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename",user,password);
```

But, for PostgreSQL, the DSN is more standard (IMO):

```
$pdoConnection = new PDO("pgsql:host=hostname;dbname=databasename;user=username;password=thepassword");
```

Is there any reason why MySQL cannot use a single string?  Or is this just because of the versions I am using (PHP 5.2, MySQL 5.0, PostgreSQL 8.1)?

Answer (score 100):

As the person that implemented both, I can tell you that the reason is that by passing the string through as-is to postgres (and ODBC) the PDO driver code for those databases does not need to be updated as the underlying library adds new features.

Since MySQL does not have its own connection string parsing code, we invented a mechanism for passing data in to the underlying MySQL function calls, which have a very specific API with fixed parameters.

No accident; it's very deliberate.

Comment: You can't argue with Wez's answer...how has this not been accepted yet? :)

Comment: I don't get it. If you had to parse the string for MySQL anyway, why not parse the username and password out of the DSN? Now we have to use multiple fields instead of just a connection string; or parse and remove the username/password from a semi-valid mysql DSN; or invent a new connection string format that works for both. Any of these solutions are easy to implement, but have to be implemented in userland for every single library that uses PDO. Ugh.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Shame for the horrible design.

The entire idea behind a DSN is to have a standard format, and this choice breaks that for one of the most popular engines.

Comment: Wow, is that really the guy who wrote PDO into PHP? LEGENDARY! Thanks for the answer also.

Comment: And I end up being in situation

$dsn = "uri:file:///c:/connection.txt";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, USER, PW);

I separate out my connectionstring but not username password, what a dumb design. I am a senior .NET architect and I can see ugliness here.

Comment: So you created a unified database interface, and then deliberately made the DSN behave differently depending on the database type you wanted to connect to? All due respect for your work, but *were you guys high*!?

Answer (score 9):

This has been resolved in PHP 7.4, as can be seen in [the new features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php).

I have confirmed it locally that we can write:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;charset=utf8mb4;user=root;password=')
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep, this API inconsistency is a major annoyance.

As a work-around, I pack the actual DSN string with an optional username and password using query-string syntax - then parse and construct like this:

```
parse_str($connection_string, $params);

$pdo = new PDO($params['dsn'], @$params['username'], @$params['password']);
```

So for PostgreSQL, use a `$connection_string` like:

```
dsn=pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test;user=root;password=root
```

And for MySQL, use a string like:

```
dsn=mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb&username=root&password=root
```

Kind of lame, but it's simple and it works.

Comment: $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servname.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";char=".$this->char;   Is this Correct Syntax or Have I got the double quotes in the wrong places?

Comment: Try using `sprintf` instead -- much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more than 10 years old, but I still end up here every time I create a new project that uses PDO... I'm writing my solution here so that I can save myself the trouble next time :P

```php
class MyPDO extends PDO {
    public function __construct($dsn, $options = null) {
        $user=null;
        $pass=null;

        if (preg_match("/user=([^;]*)/", $dsn, $matches)) {
            $user=$matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/password=([^;]*)/", $dsn, $matches)) {
            $pass=$matches[1];
        }

        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    }
}
```