# PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, pdo

There are tons of questions asked on this topic on Stack Overflow, but none of them matches my case.

I am using Lampp with PHP 5.4.7 and it was running fine until I developed my first PDO program in PHP.

When I use

`$con=new PDO("mysql:host='localhost';dbname='data';charset=utf8",'root','');`

for connection I get this error.Do I need to activate something in php.ini?

Comment: (*related*) [Why is PHP PDO DSN a different format for MySQL versus PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237367/why-is-php-pdo-dsn-a-different-format-for-mysql-versus-postgresql)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> "mysql:host='localhost';dbname='data';charset=utf8"

Your DSN format is wrong, it shouldn't have those quotes in there. This is the right format

```
 //$con=new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
 $con=new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1','root','');
```

[See Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Also, if you are using variable to represent $host, make sure that the curly braces are ok. example. {$host}. A missing opening or closing brace may result in a wrong value, and host is not reachable.

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't copying the IP address with any trailing space and pasting it as it is and then spend 20 minutes troubleshoot why the new staging version doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Try using localhost ip instead: `127.0.0.1` and remove the quotes around dbname and host:

`$con=new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=data;charset=utf8",'root','');`

Comment: I had a similar after the recent update. My env contained "localhost" and I suddenly started to get the error in the question. Then I changed it to 127.0.0.1 and it works.  Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

### For the case when you have a `.env` file.

DO NOT USE `'` (single quote) for values on DB settings.
For example the following must be written:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
```

NOT!!! `DB_CONNECTION='mysql'` etc.

Comment: You solve my problem, really thank you!