# Unknown host Connection Failure in PDO MySQL

Tags: php, pdo

Connection output failed I already change the quotations but still it failed

This is my code in config.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "db_airlines'";


try{
    $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host= ' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
    echo $host;
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Failed to connect to database";
} ?>
```

> failed output prompts: Warning: PDO::__construct():
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

but if I change it to `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost'; $username, $password); // this works.`

Why is that?

Comment: `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password);` you have space before your hostname

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377348/pdo-construct-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
```

The Space before your host name is causing this issue.