# Error connecting to mysql database.

Tags: php, pdo

It might be a duplicate, but i went through all the solution that are suggested in other posts at stackoverflow but cannot find a solution.

```
 <?php
$PDO= new PDO('mysql:host= 127.0.0.1; dbname = social_network; charset= utf8', 'root', '' );
$PDO-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

?>
```

The error i am having is as follows:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host= 127...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php on line 2

I appreciate your quick asnwer.

Comment: You Can Check The Link Provided By ,, `Mame Medoune Diop` ... Its Explain The `Charset` From Here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @gview I hv removed all the spaces. Still the same error.

Comment: Please get a mysql command line or phpmyadmin session on your db and run these queries:  select @@version;  show character set like 'u%';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra extra space in the DSN which is count as a part of charset name, so it has to be removed.

```
<?php
$servername = 127.0.0.1;  //localhost
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "social_network";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Tried it by writing localhost. Also removed the charset. Now it has two errors.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host= loc...', 'root', '') #1 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Comment: @NazmusSakib Just Replace Your Code With My Code .. I already change the all details of as same your `database` and `username` so there is no problem you can replace it with my code

Comment: Can You  Update Your Question With Your Full Code. Bcoz its not an error of connection !!

Comment: @NazmusSakib .. change the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and try it again

Comment: Yes your code works. But i would love to know why my code does not work. :(

Comment: @NazmusSakib ... As Per Error .. Your 1st error for .. This ... Check ::  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377348/pdo-construct-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servic

Comment: The error is same after changing it the localhost to 127.0.0.1. Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php(4): PDO->__construct('mysql:host= 127...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\social_network\create_account.php on line 4

Comment: @NazmusSakib .. Yes You Can Check The ,... Ans Here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo   ... as per `Mame Medoune Diop` Suggested .. here Is Explain the Charset for PDO

Answer (score 3):

you just have to remove the white space in "charset= utf8". So you would have "charset=utf8".

Answer (score 1):

For the charset need to be specific which is being used in XAMPP/WAMP.

You can change charset=utf8 **To** charset=utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$database = 'social_network';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$charset = 'utf8';
$options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
    ];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=$charset";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
```

This should work! Check this url (https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) PDO is better explained there! Your issus is about the charset